# Plotting processing time

Tags: excel, charts

Below is the average time taken for a robot to process a single request on any given day. I am trying to plot this on an excel chart but I am having trouble formatting. I want the date on the x axis and the processing time on the y axis. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
11/23/2017  0:02:40
11/24/2017  0:02:33
11/25/2017  0:02:54
11/26/2017  0:02:50
11/27/2017  0:03:01
11/28/2017  0:02:42
11/29/2017  0:03:07
11/30/2017  0:02:42
12/1/2017   0:02:55
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a line chart. With the data in two columns, make sure there is a header row. Delete any content in the date header, so the cell is blank. If there is text in the column header, Excel will try to plot the dates as numbers, and that is not what you want.

Click any cell in the table and insert a line chart. By default, if Excel recognizes a date for the X axis values, it will plot the data on a timeline. In the screenshot, notice that there is a gap of a few days and the chart plots the data correctly per day.

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly for me! The column header is what got me. thank you so much.